# Javascript - map object members to return new flattened object

Tags: javascript, lodash

Is there a simpler way to achieve the code below? Answer using lodash will be also accepted.

```
var obj = {
    dataTable: {
      column1: ["1"],
      column2: ["2"],
      column3: ["3"]
    },
    dataTable2: {
      column4: ["4"],
      column5: ["5"],
      column6: ["6"]
    }     
}    

var result = {};
var keys = Object.keys(obj);

keys.forEach(function(key) {
  var fields = Object.keys(obj[key]);
  fields.forEach(function(field) {
    result[field] = obj[key][field][0];
  });
});

console.log(result)
---> {column1: "1", column2: "2", column3: "3", column4: "4", column5: "5", column6: "6"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use forOwn function (https://lodash.com/docs#forOwn)

```
 var result = {};
    _.forOwn(object, function(value, key){
      result[key] = value[0];
    })
```

for 2-level nesting you could use that method twice:

```
var result = {};
_.forOwn(obj, function(value1, key){
  _.forOwn(value1, function(value2, key){
    result[key] = value2[0];
  })
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with two `for...in` loops

```js
var obj = {
  dataTable: {
    column1: ["1"],
    column2: ["2"],
    column3: ["3"]
  }, 
  dataTable2: {
    column4: ["4"],
    column5: ["5"],
    column6: ["6"]
  }     
}, result = {}

for (p in obj) {
  for (a in obj[p]) {
    result[a] = obj[p][a].join('');
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Fast, simple and clean. Just don't forget to declare vars `p` and `a`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursion:

```
myFn= (u,o,k)=> {
    if (o.map == [].map) u[k] = o[0];
    else for (k in o) myFn(o[k],k)
}
```

The above function will search *ALL* nested levels, and will populate your object accordingly.

To use, simple do this:

```
var output = {};
myFn(output, obj);

console.log(output);
// {column1: "1", column2: "2", column3: "3", column4: "4", column5: "5", column6: "6"}
```

Answer (score 1):

The kind of tasks where ES6 really shines.

```
const res = Object.assign(...Object.keys(obj).map(x => obj[x]))
Object.keys(res).forEach(x => res[x] = res[x][0])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a lodash solution that uses [reduce()](https://lodash.com/docs#reduce) to [merge()](https://lodash.com/docs#merge) all `datatable` objects and then use [mapValues()](https://lodash.com/docs#mapValues) to set each of the `column` values by using [head()](https://lodash.com/docs#head).

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ugm3h1xg/1/)**

```
var result = _.chain(obj)
  .reduce(_.merge) // merge all values
  .mapValues(_.head) // set the first item of the array as the value
  .value();
```